# Hive list of reserved words

Tags: hive

Can anybody point me to a **page listing all the reserved words in Hive**?

There are many questions here aimed to *using* the reserved words as a column or table names *after* such columns or tables were created. My question is about **how to avoid *creating* such columns or tables**.

If you google "some_DBMS reserved words", the first hit is the official page.
I.e., here it's for [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), here for [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html), here for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), etc. But not for Hive.

[Here is the only page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) I was able to find, but it's inaccurate - it does not include the `DIV` keyword, which is empirically found to be reserved.

Comment: `DIV` is an operator rather than a keyword. The list of operators and functions is here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF. You can also use `SHOW FUNCTIONS` to see the list applicable to your Hive version.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into the code and found it to be in:

/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/HiveLexerParent.g

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/rel/release-3.1.0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/HiveLexer.g

Answer (score 0):

You can get reserve keyword of hive:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

Comment: This is the very link I have already provided in my question, along with the reason I am not happy with this link (it does not include at least one reserved word - DIV). Also, it does not explain what's the difference between the "reserved keywords" and "non-reserved keywords".